# Can I use wavfile.write() to write chords to a .wav file using a 2D numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, signal-processing

I'm trying to learn how to make music in python. Specifically, write two notes being played simultaneously to a .wav file.

Right now, I have a 2d matrix

```
g = 
array([[   0.        ,   76.32305686,  152.54007653, ...,  550.85754483,
     247.01881968,  -58.19218202],
   [   0.        ,  384.16771547,  764.94854197, ...,  504.96037932,
     121.4972783 , -263.03696371]])
```

I first tried the following (where from scipy.io I have imported wavfile)

```
wavfile.write('pure_c.wav', rate=44100, data=g.astype(np.int16))
```

and then tried

```
wavfile.write('pure_c.wav', rate=44100, data=g)
```

(because maybe it doesn't need to be set as np, since it's already a numpy data structure?

I keep getting the error that "ushort format requires 0 <= number <= 0xffff"

Can anyone please advise how to get simultaneous waves into a .wav file? If not, do any of you have solid resources on how to produce music using coding languages?

Thanks so much

Chuck

Comment: from https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.write.html I see they normalize their input. You should try to get all your values between : +/- amplitude = np.iinfo(np.int16).max. Or maybe you use 32-bit floating-point wavfile then you get float values between -1 and 1; or PCM then change your values as integers too.

Comment: @Apo Is there a reason the same restriction doesn't hold with a one-dimensional input? When I give it a single array, it handles it fine, regardless of +/- amplitude

Thanks for your help, in any case!